# How can I bind a List<T> to relevant text boxes on a form?

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface, data-binding, binding

I have the following classes:

```
public class TemplateTestLine
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string Hyperlink { get; set; }
        public int NumOfReadings { get; set; }
        public UnitOfMeasure UnitOfMeasure { get; set; } = new UnitOfMeasure();
        public MethodOfInput MethodOfInput { get; set; } = new MethodOfInput();  
        public bool Alarm { get; set; }
        public bool Signature { get; set; }
        public List<TemplateReading> Readings { get; set; } = new List<TemplateReading>();
    }

 public class TemplateReading
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int TestLineId { get; set; }
        public int ReadingTypeId { get; set; }
        public string Value { get; set; }
    }
```

In my database I have a number of reading types, which relate to the `ReadingTypeId` like so...

```
Id  Description
----------------
1   Distance Between Readings
2   Readings Target Min
3   Readings Target Max
4   Max Difference Between Readings
5   Tolerance Between Jumps
6   Straightness Max Difference Between Readings
7   Straightness Tolerance Between Jumps
8   Straightness Target Min
9   Straightness Target Max
10  Readings Tolerance Min
11  Readings Tolerance Max
12  Straightness Tolerance Min
13  Straightness Tolerance Max
```

To create or edit a `TemplateTestLine` I have a form with inputs(mainly text boxes) that I want to bind to the `TemplateTestLine` object that is passed to the form. So, 7 for each of the main properties (which are easy enough to bind using the 'Advanced DataBinding Editor'), plus 13 text boxes for the `List<TemplateReading>` like so...

[image: current user interface]

**So my question is....**

How can I bind the readings text boxes on the form so that when I pass a `TemplateTestLine` to the form, the `List<TemplateReading>` populate their relevant `ReadingTypeId` text boxes with the `Value` property?

Can it be done from the 'Advanced Binding Editor' or will I need to forget that and come up with a coded solution?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's simple enough to bind a Property of one of the objects in the list to the `Text` Property of the related TextBox (e.g., `[TextBox].DataBindings.Add("Text", [TemplateTestLine Instance].Readings.Single(r => r.ReadingTypeId == 1), "Value", false, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);)` -- Question: is the number of IDs always limited to 13 and always will be? Are you sure all the properties in the `TemplateTestLine` class should have a `public` setter? Are you performing validation on the Form that shows those values? The class itself doesn't appear to have any.

Comment: Thank you, that is really useful and works great. There is a likelihood that there will be more than 13 ID's,  at which point I would need to add additional text boxes to the form (which I don't like). But I cannot think of a 'dynamic' way that this interface could be built to cater for that eventuality. Any thoughts/guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: I'd probably build something collapsible / expandable, i.e., a Control which defines its layout based on the content that is submitted (similar to, e.g., the PropertyGrid) -- You could also add UserControls to a TableLayoutPanel (some UCs may span more than one Column).

Comment: Thanks again @Jimi, I will explore those options.

Comment: @Jimi if you want to post your comment as an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To close this question, @Jimi's solution in the comments worked great:

*"It's simple enough to bind a Property of one of the objects in the list to the Text Property of the related TextBox"*

`[TextBox].DataBindings.Add("Text", [TemplateTestLine Instance].Readings.Single(r => r.ReadingTypeId == 1), "Value", false, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);`

Thanks